# Wordpress: Remove comments from a category

Tags: wordpress, themes, categories

First of all, I am a beginner in Wordpress. This blog I made is from a theme I made from scratch. Is it possible to remove comments from a certain category? As in for a category called "News", there won't be a comment box. Only posts with the category called "Blog" will have comments there.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-disable-comments/ . Even a simple Google search would have worked.